# Assigning a type to a model on registration using a drop down menu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, selector, registration

I am using devise for registration of new users.  Users have an attribute, account_type, and I would like to give them the option to select their account type from a drop down menu on the registration page.  Which method would be good to use here and how would I set it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Run `rails generate devise:views` or `rails generate devise:views users` to generate views for further customization
2. Add the `account_type` to the registrations form in `devise/registrations/new.html.erb` or `users/registrations/new.html.erb` depending how you generated
3. Add `account_type` to `attr_accessible` to allow it for mass assignment `attr_accessible :account_type`

Users should now be able to select their account_type.

Comment: Thanks!  Do you know what method I could use to create the drop down menu?

Comment: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select or http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag